# grant_type in Spring-Security-OAuth2

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am new to OAuth2 concept.I ahve to implement this in my application. This application provides REST APIs. I follwed some tutorial ,done some research and kind of implemented it in working state in my application.

But while doing some search I read about different type of `grant_type` in OAuth2. I tried to learn about that but didn't get actual differences and which should I use for securing REST APIs. 
So I want to know that for `grant_type` types "password","client_credential"etc which should be used and in which scenario, or which should be used for securing REST APIs?

Also at some places I found that the request for `/oauth/token` is different. 
Some places the `Authorization` header is given as `Basic 'some_encoded_string'` .
And at some place it is Bearer 'some_encoded_string'. Whats the difference in these request?

Summarizing this I have 2 question -

1. For `grant_type` types "password","client_credential"etc which should be used and in which scenario, or which should be used for securing REST APIs?
2. What is the difference in ways of requesting token from `/oauth/token` .

Enlight my knowledge in implementing spring-security-oauth2.

Answer (score 4):

The grant you need to use depends on your use case and the nature of the client application accessing your resources. There isn't a grant that applies a `REST API`resource in general. You'd need to provide more information on what the APIs are and how you interact with them.

If a user has to give their permissions for a client to access an API, then you would normally use an "authorization code" grant. If the client accesses the resource directly without the intervention of an end user then it would normally use the "client credentials" grant.

You should avoid using the `password` grant in most cases, since it means the user has to provide their username and password to the client application. If the application can use another grant, such as authorization code, then that is preferable. A trusted application, such as a native application which the user installs on their computer, would be one situation where the password grant might be used.

A client would normally use "Basic" authentication to access the token endpoint. "Bearer" authentication is use to access a protected resource (such as your API), passing the access token it obtained from the authorization server.

Why do you think you need to use OAuth2 at all? I'm curious since you say you don't understand what the grant types are for. You really need to understand this before you can make a judgement about how you would use OAuth2 or why.

Comment: Its needed for the project So I am using OAuth2 and Yes I don't understand its concept but It doesn't mean I'll never understand this.

Comment: You told that `password` grant type should not be used in most cases ,but you didn't explain that in which condition we should use that grant-type ? Also can you explain a bit more the token request with Basic type Authorization header.

Comment: I've added a bit more on the password grant. Without more information about why your application needs OAuth2 though, it's hard to give specific answers about what you should use (or if it even makes sense). All the details of token requests and so on are covered in the [spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749), so I'd recommend you take a look there for the details.